# ¿Cómo guardar registros de una tabla desde el template a la base de datos en Django?

Tags: django

Estoy realizando mi primera aplicación con **Django** y no puedo recoger los datos de una tabla desde la plantilla para actualizar la base de datos. Lo que quiero es capturar las calificaciones de un grupo de alumnos y al presionar el botón guardar se guarden en la base de datos.

En la vista obtengo la lista de alumnos, por ejemplo:

```
  alumnos = Alumno.objects.all().order_by("nombre")
```

y mando la variable alumnos al template y con un *for*:

```
{% for alumno in alumnos %}
```

Creo una tabla con dos columnas, en la primera pongo `{{ alumno.nombre }}` y en la segunda un `textbox` para que el docente asigne la calificación.

Lo que no sé es como puedo recoger las calificaciones de los `textboxs` para guardarlos en la base de datos.

Comment: Esto se resuelve en la documentación del framework. A menos que exista un problema real que responder, voto por cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: @toledano si fuera por eso, la mitad de las preguntas aquí tendrían que ser cerradas.

Comment: Django forms, si dejas tus modelos quizá habría como ayudarte mejor